# BeautifulSoup: can't find the text in the nest

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image: cant extract the sales]

I'm trying to get to the number of sales but I can't seem to reach the nest?

I've built this function so far and I can extract the spans, but can't go over the spans... :(

I've tried extracting it using the class (and regex to make it less specific) but to no avail. I've also tried using `.find_all('span',c)`

```
def getInfo(listing_link):
    
    response = requests.get(listing_link)
    html = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    
    #print(len(list(soup.descendants)))
    
    c = re.compile("wt-text-caption ")
    

    for child in soup.find_all('div'):
        for baby in child.descendants: 
            bar = baby.find('span')
            print(bar)
            for i in bar:
                sales = i.find_all("span", c)
```

Comment: you have a url?

Comment: The class name does not include the spaces, but your regex does.  And there's no need for a regex; just search for the class name as a string.   `soup.find_all("span", {'class': 'wt-text-caption'})`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('span', attrs={"class":"wt-text-caption"})
```

Comment: I get an empty string when I print the solution to that :/